# Group by in SQL OR Sequelize which where check and where in count as well

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I have a table with columns
id, type, type(this can be test1,test2, test3)

it need a query or sequelize solution as i have added both options in my code, query should give me result like.
Group by url & give me result like that
url, count of test1 occurences, count of test2, count of test3 like this

it gives me count of all row, i need count of where type is 1, type is 2, type is 3.

> SELECT `url`, count(`type`) AS `count` FROM `table` AS `table`  GROUP
>   BY `type`

```
table.findAll({
        where: {

        },
        attributes: ['url', 
            [db.fn('count', db.col('type')), 'count']
        ], 
        group: ['type'],
        // order: [['created_at', 'DESC']]
    })
```

I need output as

```
 [
       {
           url: 'abc.com',
           test1_count: 3,
           test2_count: 5,
           test3_count: 8,
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT url, count(1) AS concat(type, ‘_count’)
FROM table 
GROUP BY url, type;
```